# Inconsistent memory limit displaying (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, memory, limit

This one is strange.

Could someone tell me why this shows different integers on the front end and back end?

If I do this...

```
$theram = (int) ini_get('memory_limit');
echo $theram;
```

...in a wordpress theme template it displays 128 (which I know is the correct PHP memory limit).

But if I do it in the wordpress backend (on a settings page of a plugin I'm creating) it displays 256.

I can't figure out why it shows double the value.

FYI this is a clean install of Wordpress, no other plugins or customisation.

Cheers!